# Dependencia moment en todo el proyecto

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quiero poder utilizar la dependencia de moment en todo el proyecto para no estar importandolo en cada uno de los controladores y si requiero de utilizarlo en una vista lo mismo.

Estoy probando de hacer lo siguiente en el app.js pero me arroja error

```
const moment = require('moment');
app.set(moment())
```

Estoy iniciando NodeJs

Comment: No se recomienda el uso de [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacerlo es añadirlo en en `global`, algo así:

```
const moment = require('moment');
global.moment = moment;
```